# RavenDb Integer values sorting

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

According to [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/customizing-results-order), numeric values are sorted as strings by default. I am curious what are the reasons behind this decision. It looks much more reasonable for me to define default SortOption according to appropriate numeric type, especially according to this:

> The default SortOptions value is String. Appropriate values available
>   for all numeric types (Byte, Double, Float, Int, Long and Short).

Comment: What is the question? If you want to suggest a feature or a change, please use the mailing list, github or supply a pull request.

Comment: I don't think I am the first who came to this. So I guess there should be some motivation behind current implementation. That's why I decided to clarify it first

Comment: Ok, so the question is something like 'What is the reason for having it implemented this way?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is really nothing that prevent you from saying things

{"Count": 123 }
{"Count": "lots" }

RavenDB is untyped, and we don't have a way of knowing what you are going to put in it.
We default to sorting as strings because that is always available, and work for most scenarios.

We can probably detect that in some cases and handle that, but that isn't something that we paid attention to.
I created an issue for that here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-10